# password recovery without saving user email

Tags: passwords, recovery

hey there.
I'm developing a website and i want to have a password recovery system for the users who lost their password, but i don't want to save the user email address or any private data.
i thought of saving a hash of the email address but if the db is compromised one could check if an email address is registered and which account it belongs to.
do you have any ideas?

Comment: How do your users sign-in ordinarily if you don't store any identifying data?

Comment: i will save a username and the hash of the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To protect against the DB being compromised and hashes extracted, just add some random (but constant string) to all email addresses before cashing. E.g. add "BLABLABLA" to turn "joe@example.com" into "joe@example.comBLABLABLA" before hashing. It's still not perfect, but now an attacker needs your DB, your application code, reverse engineer it, and know that that's what he needs to do in the first place (there is no hint in the DB that your application modifies the email address before hashing).

Comment: You could make it even more secure by reading the constant string from an external file on start-up and then delete the file (you better remember the string as you have to recreate the file on restart)

Comment: i was thinking more like, the goverment seizes my server i don't have any data that could identify beyond any doubt my users. I finally decided to reset accounts after 30 days without use.